# How to show a table as a tooltip using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a Gridview populated with data and one of the column contains a Link Button (File List). If I click on the Linkbutton (FileList) a .net event will be fired and a call will be made to the database to retrieve the data.

How to show that data in a HTML table format as a tool-tip as shown in the attached picture? I would like to achieve the tooltip using jQuery.

[image]

Comment: what format is the retrieved data in? JSON? HTML Markup?

Comment: Data is retrieved in JSON format

Answer (score 13):

Simple example:

HTML

```
<a href="">test</a>
<table>
    <tr><td>asdf</td><td>gsdi</td></tr>
    <tr><td>asdf</td><td>gsdi</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('a').hover(function(ev){
    $('table').stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
},function(ev){
    $('table').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
}).mousemove(function(ev){
    $('table').css({left:ev.layerX+10,top:ev.layerY+10});
});
```

CSS

```
table{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
td{
    border:1px solid red;   
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Unyeg/)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!.=D +1

Answer (score 0):

Andy's response above work but the "layerX" and "layerY" have been deprecated. While using Firefox, Chrome or Safari, when using "layerX" the tool-tip kept blinking on the top of the commented text.

You may it with replaced with "clientX" and "clientY": while using Firefox, Chrome or Safari, "clientX" worked with no trouble.