# Need help to create a table inside tooltip SWT

Tags: java, swt, tooltip

Basically I'm designing a SWT UI where I have placed a Label as Image icon on which when the mouse entered the icon pops up a tooltip with table I have referred to many websites but was not able find one example or help to do it

my code look like this

```
Myicon= Components.createLabel(temp, SWT.RIGHT);
Myicon.setImage(MY_IMG);
Myicon.setVisible(True);
Loop();
Myicon.settooltipText(FIRST_COLOUM+ "/t"+ SECOND_COLOUM);
```

The problem with this is the text is not getting text aligned so i decide to apply a table instead of setting a string

So can you help me through it

the example one is which i'm trying to follow is this

[How to show a table as a tooltip using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654711/how-to-show-a-table-as-a-tooltip-using-jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/Unyeg/

its in jquery and i need to do in SWT and no styling/ html

Comment: Is this application just SWT? The JFace `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` class has a lot of code to support controls in a tool tip since this is quite hard to do in just SWT.

Comment: for now its being developed purely on SWT that's why i needed help. The layout is designed in grids so there is not a possibility to add table and make its visibility(false) and write it as true when mouse in In. The implementation can be complex. If there is a possible solution to do it using Jface i'll try to do it . i need some tutorial on that part

Comment: \t, \n characters are not working in tool tip text?

Comment: The thing is /t and /n working fine but the Problem using them is they give a designated length. and i'm my stings are like too long or too short the longest string is about 32 length and shortest is about 5 and i have calculated the string length and  placed it in the padding but the problem shows up with the default font. so we decided to implement a table in the tooltip instead of adjusting all the way the same methodology is being followed in more places so its better to have a standard solution